# Build a hierarchical menu with multiple nodes location

Tags: 7, navigation

I look for one (or more) module (s) to allow me to have an organization such as in **Drupal 7** :

- A node can be in one or more section of the menu
- It will have its own URL to reach each of its sections and we keep the section when one consults
- and so own breadcrumb by location
- the node are not necessarily display in the menu, we can see the node when we are displaying the section, not directly in the menu.

example:

**section 1**

- section 1.1
- section 1.2 ( contains 2 nodes related : node 1 , node 2
  )

  - section 1.2.1 ( contains 1 node related : node 4)

**section 2**

- section 2.1 (contains 2 nodes related : node 2, node 3)
- section 2.2

*When I click to this link section 1.2 (URL :  /section1/section1-2 )*

We display : node 1, node 2, section 1.2.1 ( display : teaser )
each teaser have a specific link :

- /section1/section1-2/node1
- /section1/section1-2/node2
- /section1/section1-2/section1-2-1

The node 4 in section 1.2.1 **isn't displayed**.

*When I click to this link section 2.1 (URL : /section2/section2-1)*

We display : node 2, node 3( display : teaser )
each teaser have a specific link :

- /section2/section2-1/node2
- /section2/section2-1/node3

So we have same content in two locations : /section2/section2-1/node2 , /section1/section1-2/node2

The menu and breadcrumb must remain the current path

*If we are in : /section2/section2-1/node2*

The section 2 , section 2-1 menu are active

The breadcrumb are section2 / section2.1

I try to use taxonomy menu to achieve but it seems that we can't have multiple locations for node.